# VUEJS pass css file to child components

Tags: vue.js

I have 4 components :

- 1 for landing page
- 1 for dashboard header
- 1 for dashboard footer
- 1 for dashboard content

All css files are scoped, but i need to include 3x the sames css files for 3 components of the dashboard

[My component structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t303E.png)

[Dashboard code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyjZG.png)

[CSS files import from dashboard composant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKsXI.png)

The imports are scoped, but I want to share this import with child (header, footer)

How can I tell my child components, to use the parent's css files ? without removing the scoped, so that it doesn't overflow on the other components ?

(Warning : it's not css in component, but file include)

The structure is :

header component

dashboard component html

footer component

Thanks in advance for helping

Kylian

Comment: Can you share a minimal example with code?

Comment: Have you tried to import or require the css file from the child component?

Comment: Yes Leo, but they're the same files, so he imports me a total of 3 times each file... And it generates me conflicts (one file is supposed to be on top of the other)

Comment: Your best bet is to give up on `scoped` and instead use CSS selector specificity - i.e. attach some hopefully unique CSS class name to your parent and then use it as the first selector in your CSS rules. For example `.my_root_component .my_child_style` will only affect child components if they are sitting inside `.my_root_component`

Comment: @Retorks Did you solve this or any workaround ?